# Microsoft Security Essentials: how to disable background scan?

Tags: windows-xp, ms-security-essentials

Microsoft recently pushed out an update to Security Essentials via Windows Update. Now when my computer is "idle", MSSE thrashes the hard drive presumably doing a background scan. I don't want this. How do I prevent it? Of course I have unchecked "Run a scheduled scan on my PC".

Comment: I've got the latest update and have not seen any background scan taking place when the PC is idle. The scheduled scan only starts when the PC is idle but it's pretty quick on my PC - about a minute.

Comment: @BJ292: The scheduled scan has options you can set. I think it defaults to "quick scan". The unrequested background scan I have no idea how to configure. Also I have a lot of junk on my hard drives - a full scan would take a very long time.

Comment: What makes you sure it is MSE?

Comment: @Xavierjazz: The CPU History and IO History columns in Process Explorer.

Comment: Perhaps you should let it run a scheduled scan so that it doesn't need to run in the background all the time.

Comment: Possibly you have something else starting when the PC is idle that then conflicts with the latest version of MSE?

Comment: @BJ292: I don't think so.